# Constant Client Disconnects in Classic ASP Web Application

Tags: javascript, iis, asp-classic

I'm working with a Classic ASP web app that typically runs well considering the old technology.  It is an online support chat application that basically refreshes the client side Live Monitor page every 10 seconds to see if there are any pending chat requests.  The past few days, a lot of our users are having a problem where this page either just ends up refreshing and going blank white (with no html in view source), or it goes to a generic IE error page "This program cannot display the webpage" - the same error you see when you are offline.  I was able to recreate the issue after hours when I was the only user in the chat system, so it's not a matter of an overloaded server I don't think.

I've tried the following to no avail:

- Recycle Application Pool
- Reboot IIS Server
- Change refresh from javascript to meta tag
- Check IIS Error logs (nothing)
- Check IIS event logs (nothing)

One thing that seemed to work for me, but didn't work for everyone else, was to disable our network Proxy server settings in the browser.  Once I disable this, I can't get it to error out anymore... however, other users aren't quite so lucky.

Any thoughts on where to go with this?  I'm at a bit of a loss here...

Thanks,
Shawn

Comment: Sounds more like network issue with your host or server, not JavsScript, IIS or code. Are you hosted or running your own web server?

Comment: Yeah I agree... how can we troubleshoot this?  It's an in-house server on the local network.

Comment: Try monitoring the network traffic in the low level (packets sent and received) with tools like WireShark and see if you spot anything unusual for a start.

Comment: do you use Response.Flush in that page? when yes take a look here: "If the Flush method is called on an ASP page, the server does not honor Keep-Alive requests for that page." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525560.aspx). try to remove response.flush and you should be fine

Comment: Yes, it does use Response.Flush actually... I'll have to check into that.  Thanks!

Comment: Well removing the Response buffering/flushing, it still times out, but now it shows up as a 500 internal server error.  The IIS log shows this as a SQL timeout error, so looking further into that now.  Thanks!

Comment: SQL timeout error in this context is typicaly **locking problems**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are finding the same problems in a .Net solution.  It looks as if the issues are related to SQL Locking so we're working on those as we find them.